# Executing fortran script with single line from Windows cmd

Tags: windows, fortran

I need to run a fortran (77) script from the Windows 10 command window, but it should be a one-liner. The reason is that the fortran scipt - a file called external_command.f - is actually part of a Matlab script, where I can run external code through the operating system's command window (by using the ! "bang" symbol or system()-command. I quickly want to point that out without focusing too much on Matlab). But I'm having trouble doing that in Windows.

So far I tried:

1. using a fortran compiler for Windows, like Msys2 (which has the functions of gfortran, as far as I understand). However, it looks like I have to start Msys2 first, which then opens a separate window, which Matlab doesn't seem to be able to use because it's not Windows cmd anymore
2. installing  gfortran in Ubuntu using Windows 10's WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Same problem here: the cmd window changes to a Ubuntu terminal before I can use any fortran scripts. Furthermore, I can't easily change files located in Windows with commands from within a virtual machine

If it's not possible to run fortran scripts in Windows 10 in a one cmd line, I'd appreciate some guidance on how to change my approach.

EDIT: after Ronald kindly explained in a comment how fortran works I think this whole (rather complicated) question is just based on my own misunderstanding of fortran. I'm pretty sure I can now solve the issue after compiling my fortran code and using the resulting exe file in my cmd-window.

Comment: FORTRAN is a language that is usually compiled, not interpreted. You don't have a script, you have a file with the source code of some program. Hence you'll have to compile it first and then invoke the resulting binary. If you compile in a Windows environment, the compiler should create some .exe file. After having created the executable, you can execute this as often as you like..

Comment: If the Fortran code is run from a Matlab program (or script if you prefer) then you should really be compiling the Fortran into a MEX file ... on which topic there is a ton of good quality documentation and a myriad of Qs and As on this site alone.